# componentDidMount called BEFORE ref callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Problem**

I'm setting a react [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) using an inline function definition

```
render = () => {
    return (
        <div className="drawer" ref={drawer => this.drawerRef = drawer}>
```

then in `componentDidMount` the DOM reference is not set

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    // this.drawerRef is not defined
```

My understanding is the `ref` callback should be run during mount, however adding `console.log` statements reveals `componentDidMount` is called **before** the ref callback function.

Other code samples I've looked at for example [this discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6249) on github indicate the same assumption, `componentDidMount` should be called **after** any `ref` callbacks defined in `render`, it's even [stated in the conversation](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6249#issuecomment-272026401)

> > So componentDidMount is fired off after all the ref callbacks have
> >     been executed?
>
> Yes.

I'm using react *15.4.1*

**Something else I've tried**

To verify the `ref` function was being called, I tried defining it on the class as such

```
setDrawerRef = (drawer) => {
  this.drawerRef = drawer;
}
```

then in `render`

```
<div className="drawer" ref={this.setDrawerRef}>
```

Console logging in this case reveals the callback is indeed being called **after** `componentDidMount`

Comment: I may be wrong, but when you are using arrow function for the render methos, it will capture value of `this` from the lexical scope outside of your class. Try to get rid of  the arrow function  syntax for your class methods and see if it helps.

Comment: this works fine to me. Are you sure refs callback calls after DidMount? Make 2 console.logs in both functions and see which one was first

Comment: I'm using 15.5.4 React

Comment: I think you are right about order. I just thought the problem may be just with the lexical scope :)

Comment: @GProst That's the nature of my question. I put console.log in both functions and componentDidMount is running first, the ref callback second.

Comment: Is there a way for you to show all your component code? I've just installed react 15.4.1 and define render and componentDidMound methods as an arrow function (as you did) and everything works fine...

Comment: @GProst Maybe there's something larger at work here, it's a pretty large (proprietary) codebase. I think I've posted the relevant portions here. Good to know I have the correct assumptions about how it should be working at least, but still no idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: Just had a similar issue-- for us, basically, we missed it on the initial `render` and thus needed to be leveraging `componentDidUpdate`, as `componentDidMount` is not part of the updating [lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).  Probably not your issue, but thought it might be worth raising as a potential solution.

Comment: Def a good poing @AlexanderNied I've seen/done the same thing in other circumstances. Was pulled off of this issue at the time, but will consider this suggestion if I can circle round to it in the future!

Comment: Same with React 16. The documentation clearly states `ref callbacks are invoked before componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate lifecycle hooks.` but this does not seem to be true :(

Comment: 1. ref arrow declaration is : `ref = {ref => { this.drawerRef = ref }}`
2. even refs are invoked before componentDidMount; ref can only be accessed after initial render when the div in your case is rendered. So, you must be able to access the ref in next level i.e., in  componentWillReceiveProps using `this.drawerRef`
3. If you try to access before initial mount you will get only either undefined values of ref.

Comment: Hi folks, if you find issues in React please file a bug next time! Thanks.

Comment: I posted another reply which might explain what’s happening.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Short answer:

**React guarantees that refs are set before `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` hooks. But only for children that *actually got rendered***.

```
componentDidMount() {
  // can use any refs here
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  // can use any refs here
}

render() {
  // as long as those refs were rendered!
  return <div ref={/* ... */} />;
}
```

Note this doesn’t mean “React always sets *all* refs before these hooks run”.
Let’s look at some examples where the refs *don’t* get set.

---

## Refs don’t get set for elements that weren’t rendered

React will only call ref callbacks for elements that you actually **returned from render**.

This means that if your code looks like

```
render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  }

  return <div ref={this._setRef} />;
}
```

and initially `this.state.isLoading` is `true`, you should **not** expect `this._setRef` to be called before `componentDidMount`.

This should make sense: if your first render returned `<h1>Loading</h1>`, there's no possible way for React to know that under some other condition it returns something else that needs a ref to be attached. There is also **nothing to set the ref to:** the `<div>` element was not created because the `render()` method said it shouldn’t be rendered.

So with this example, only `componentDidMount` will fire. However, **when `this.state.loading` changes to `false`**, you will see `this._setRef` attached first, and then `componentDidUpdate` will fire.

---

## Watch out for other components

Note that **if you pass children with refs down to other components** there is a chance they’re doing something that prevents rendering (and causes the issue).

For example, this:

```
<MyPanel>
  <div ref={this.setRef} />
</MyPanel>
```

wouldn't work if `MyPanel` did not include `props.children` in its output:

```
function MyPanel(props) {
  // ignore props.children
  return <h1>Oops, no refs for you today!</h1>;
}
```

Again, it’s not a bug: **there would be nothing for React to set the ref to because the DOM element was not created**.

---

## Refs don’t get set before lifecycles if they’re passed to a nested `ReactDOM.render()`

Similar to the previous section, if you pass a child with a ref to another component, it’s possible that this component may do something that prevents attaching the ref in time.

For example, maybe it’s not returning the child from `render()`, and instead is calling `ReactDOM.render()` in a lifecycle hook. You can find an example of this [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12034). In that example, we render:

```
<MyModal>
  <div ref={this.setRef} />
</MyModal>
```

But `MyModal` performs a `ReactDOM.render()` call in *its* `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  ReactDOM.render(this.props.children, this.targetEl);
}

render() {
  return null;
}
```

Since React 16, such **top-level render calls during a lifecycle will be delayed until lifecycles have run for the whole tree**. This would explain why you’re not seeing the refs attached in time.

**The solution to this problem is to use 
[portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) instead of nested `ReactDOM.render` calls:**

```
render() {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.targetEl);
}
```

This way our `<div>` with a ref is actually included in the render output.

So if you encounter this issue, you need to verify there’s nothing between your component and the ref that might delay rendering children.

## Don't use `setState` to store refs

Make sure you are not using `setState` to store the ref in ref callback, as it's asynchronous and before it's "finished", `componentDidMount` will be executed first.

---

## Still an Issue?

If none of the tips above help, file an issue in React and we will take a look.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to explain this situation too. See first section. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @DanAbramov thanks for this! Unfortunately I was unable to develop a reproducible case when I first encountered it. Sadly I no longer work on that project and have been unable to repro since then. The question has become popular enough though, that I agree, trying to find the reproducible case is key as many folks seem to be experiencing the issue.

Comment: I think it's likely in many cases this was due to a misunderstanding. In React 15 this could also happen due to an error that got swallowed (React 16 has better error handling and prevents this). I'm happy to review more cases when this happens, so feel free to add them in the comments.

Comment: Helps! I didn't really noticed that there was a preloader.

Comment: How do I know ref is rendered in componentDidMount ? ` this.myInput.current.addEventListener('load', () => {
      console.log(this.myInput.current.clientWidth` does not work

Comment: This answer really helped me. I was struggling with some empty "refs" reference, and well, it turned out the "elements" weren't being rendered at all.

Comment: So this means that Ref will only be defined in componentDidUpdate() if you are trying to set ref for elements populated as a part of api calls from componentDidMount() function right ?

Answer (score 1):

A different observation of the problem.

I've realised that the issue only occurred while in development mode.
After more investigation, I found that disabling `react-hot-loader` in my Webpack config prevents this problem.

I am using

- "react-hot-loader": "3.1.3"
- "webpack": "4.10.2",

And it's an electron app.

**My partial Webpack development config**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.config.base')

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {

  entry: [
    // REMOVED THIS -> 'react-hot-loader/patch',
    `webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:${port}/__webpack_hmr`,
    '@babel/polyfill',
    './app/index'
  ],
  ...
})
```

It became suspicious when I saw that using inline function in render () was working, but using a bound method was crashing.

**Works in any case**

```
class MyComponent {
  render () {
    return (
      <input ref={(el) => {this.inputField = el}}/>
    )
  }
}
```

**Crash with react-hot-loader** (ref is undefined in componentDidMount)

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.inputRef = this.inputRef.bind(this)
  }

  inputRef (input) {
    this.inputField = input
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <input ref={this.inputRef}/>
    )
  }
}
```

To be honest, hot reload has often been problematic to get "right". With dev tools updating fast, every project has a different config.
Maybe my particular config could be fixed. I'll let you know here if that's the case.

Comment: This might explain why I'm having problems in with this in CodePen, but using an inline function hasn't helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can also arise when you try to use a ref of a unmounted component like using a ref in setinterval and do not clear set interval during component unmount.

```
componentDidMount(){
    interval_holder = setInterval(() => {
    this.myref = "something";//accessing ref of a component
    }, 2000);
  }
```

always clear interval like for example,

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(interval_holder)
}
```