# Are there any advantages of React's synthetic events vs. addEventListener?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that manages an HTML audio element. AFAIU there are two ways this can be accomplished: Put the audio element as a property on the class instance with, or put it in the `render()` method and stick a `ref` on it.

Because the second option does not create the audio element directly, but via React.createElement, I can use Reacts synthetic event system - while the first option requires adding event listeners with addEventListener. My question is, if there are any advantages of the second option?

(Option 1)

```
class A extends React.Component {
  audio = new Audio();
  componentDidMount() {
    this.audio.addEventListener('play', () => console.log('Started playing'));
  }
  play() {
    this.audio.play();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.play}>Play</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

(Option 2)

```
class A extends React.Component {
  play() {
    this.audio.play();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <audio
          ref={audio => this.audio = audio}
          onPlay={() => console.log('Started playing')}
        />
        <button onClick={this.play}>Play</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synthetic event is just a wrapper for normal events. They are there to provide a common interface between browser inconsistencies and large amounts of events ultimately perform better because of [event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

You are access the orginial event through [e.nativeEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

Comment: Note that event pooling means, that the event [cannot be accessed in an asynchronous way](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling). This is e.g. [relevant for debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28046731/6826422).

Answer (score 1):

Synthetic events are better in the sense that they are easier to use (much less code, supported without hassle between all browsers) and they are more reliable since React adds them after the element in rendered and is available in the DOM. When `componentDidMount` is called you can't be sure if the element is actually present in the browser DOM. `componentDidMount` is called when React tells the browser to append the element to DOM and has calculated the necessary stuff in it's own virtual DOM. But the browser may not render the element if the render thread is busy in any way.

Comment: Oh, my understanding was that `componentDidMount` being called in the "commit phase" means it is safe to work with refs.

Comment: Not always. Always check for the ref and if it's available. If not, set a timeout for maybe 0.1 second.

Comment: Have you run into this problem? The React docs state that ["ref updates happen before componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate lifecycle hooks"](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element). Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019873/6826422).