# Confusion on the use of synthetic events in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was learning React and came across the term Synthetic events and its benefits. I found out that there is a question [Are there any advantages of React's synthetic events vs. addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631072/are-there-any-advantages-of-reacts-synthetic-events-vs-addeventlistener) which was asked before in the platform but confused me a bit thus decided to ask for clarification. Firstly, "Synthetic event is just a wrapper for normal events. They are there to provide a common interface between browser inconsistencies" so the question is what kind of inconsistencies browsers have that synthetic events aims to solve. Secondly, "Synthetic events are faster" the question is e.g say, we have onChange events for 5 inputs and onClick events for 3 buttons, is it true that thanks to synthetic events only one onChange and one onClick are attached to document.body and e.g when we click a button, listener is attached to the clicked button only when we click that button?

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of inconsistencies browsers have that synthetic event aims to solve.

React normalizes events so that they have **consistent properties** across different browsers.

For example `MouseEvent.clientX` may return a `long` or a `double` type.

> is it true that thanks to synthetic events only one onChange and one onClick are attached to document.body and e.g when we click a button, the listener is attached to the clicked button only when we click that button

You can make an example and debug it in dev tools to validate it.

Comment: For the sake of interest, I've created a sample to check whether listeners are attached to document or directly to the elements. And turns out, `React` only adds **one listener** to document and none to the elements - optimizations are everywhere :)

Comment: Yeah right, React uses event delegation whenever it's possible