# React ref to access node dimension has current as null

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, ref

I'm trying to use `React.createRef()` to access the dimensions of a DOM element in React.

I create in in the constructor like

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.container = React.createRef()
}
```

And assigning it like

```
  <div id="container"
  ref={this.container}
  >...children</div>
```

However when I log this out from within `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount(){
console.log(this.container);
}
```

I see `{current: null}` in the console.  But if I expand this object I can see everything I want access to like clientHeight which has a value.

[image]

How do I access these attributes?  At the moment `this.container.current.clientHeight` returns null.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to log `client` or `clientHeight`?

Comment: clientHeight - typo in original question

Comment: Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074747/componentdidmount-called-before-ref-callback

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really resolve my issue as this doesn't appear to be true `React guarantees that refs are set before componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate hooks. But only for children that actually got rendered.` As the child has been rendered.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Check if you have any asynchronous code that can prevent referenced element from rendering. If so make sure that you use your ref AFTER the element has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

here is my sample code:

```
class Badge extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.textWidth = React.createRef();
this.state = {
  width: ""
};
}

 componentDidMount() {
this.textWidth.current.addEventListener("load", this.getWidth());
}

 getWidth = () => {
this.setState({
  width: this.textWidth.current.clientWidth + 30
 });
};

render() {
  return (
  <div
    style={{
      width: this.state.width
     }}
     className="badge"
   >
     <p ref={this.textWidth}>{this.props.children}</p>
   </div>
  );
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you adding a load event listener?  Is this not what componentDidMount should be doing?

Comment: because if you don't use this you won't get client attr. Content in ref element takes time to load.

Comment: Where have you got this info from?  I can't see anywhere in the react docs which suggest you should do this.  It doesn't seem very reacty to call addEventListener.

It's also still null if I try this `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: componentDidMount(){
        this.container.current.addEventListener('load', () => {
          console.log(this.container.current.clientWidth);
        })
  }

Comment: Hi raju, and welcome to stackoverflow. Rather than pasting code and 'try this' answers, some explaination providing the answer could be better.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. check my sandbox code and open console.

https://codesandbox.io/s/145wq8w1m3

Comment: @Harvey I just gave him a live example code so he can understand clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I know have it working, wrapping the component being rendered in `App` in the div rather than rendering the div within the child component

Comment: Great! mark it as answered it will motivate me and other people know that this is a correct answer.

Comment: @RajuChoudhary how could I make this example using React hooks?