# Setting focus via a ref only works in setTimeout in React?

Tags: reactjs

My code below works but the `this.buttonRef.current.firstChild.focus()` stops working if it's not in a setTimeout function.

From looking at the official docs for refs I cant see why this is happening. Is there anything obviously wrong with my component? If not Im wondering if another component on my site is 'stealing' focus as when the `url` prop changes a modal is closed.

UPDATE: One weird thing is if I `console.log` outside of the setTimeout then I can see the element is present in the DOM.

UPDATE2: Turns out it was React Trap Focus in my modal that was causing the issue. Removing the focus trap means I don't need the timeout. As I need the focus trap I think the setTimeout will need to stay.

https://github.com/davidtheclark/focus-trap-react

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buttonRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.url === '' && prevProps.url = "old-url") {
      console.log('target element: ', this.buttonRef.current.firstChild)

      // This doenst work if not in a setTimeout
      // this.buttonRef.current.firstChild.focus();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.buttonRef.current.firstChild.focus();
      }, 1);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      limitIsReached,
        add
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Title>My title</Title>
        <Section>
          <Button>
            Add a promo code
          </Button>
          <span ref={this.buttonRef}>
            {limitIsReached ? (
              <Alert
                message="Sorry limit reached"
              />
            ) : (
              <Button
                onClick={add}
              >
                Add new
              </Button>
            )}
          </span>

          <List compact />
        </Section>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Have you [seen this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074747/componentdidmount-called-before-ref-callback)?

Comment: @Tholle Ive updated my question. Yes I have but as console.log works I don't think I'm seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that seemingly componentDidUpdate runs before your buttonRef is resolved, a short setTimeout isn't the worst solution.

You could try other ways involving setting state:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (.... oldurl) {
    this.setState({focusBtn: true})
  }
```

Then when the buttonref resolves:

```
<span ref={ref=>{
  if (this.state.focusBtn) {
    this.buttonRef = ref;
    this.buttonRef.current.firstChild.focus();
  } } >...
```

EDIT

ok so if you remove the conditional in your render method, React will ensure that your ref has resolved on componentDidMount and also componentDidUpdate (as you wish it to be)

Try this:

```
<span ref={this.buttonRef}>

          <Alert
            message="Sorry limit reached"
            style={{display: limitIsReached ? 'block' : 'none'}}
          />

          <Button
            onClick={add} style={{display: limitIsReached ? 'none' : 'inline-block'}}
          >
            Add new
          </Button>
        )}
      </span>
```

Comment: I need logic in componentDidUpdate so that focus is only applied after a specific url change. You your code not apply the focus when the component was first rendered?

Comment: did removing the conditional render help?