# React Ref: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I have these refs in my constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //All Refs
    this.sunglassesTintsTab = React.createRef();
    this.gradientTintsTab = React.createRef();
    this.fashionTintsTab = React.createRef();
    this.lensTintStandardSwatchesContainer = React.createRef();
    this.lensTintMirrorSwatchesContainer = React.createRef();
}
```

And this is my componentDidMount

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('ComponentDidMount Start');
    if (this.state.modalType === 'lensTintsBlokz') {
      this.getLensTintSwatches('blokz');
    } else {
      this.setState({ lensTintsTabsContainerHidden: false });
      this.getLensTintSwatches('sunglasses');
    }
  }
```

In the getLensTintSwatches function - this is being called in componentDidMount

```
this.lensTintStandardSwatchesContainer.current.innerHTML = '';
this.lensTintMirrorSwatchesContainer.current.innerHTML = '';
```

I'm getting the following error.

**`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`**

I have tried both the standard React.createRef() and callback style ref but the current value of all the refs is returning null. What am I doing wrong here?

> UPDATE: I'm passing `ref={this.xyxRef}` as prop in the respective
> elements.
>
> Another observation-  The console.log in componentDidMount is not
> triggered, based on other console errors

This is the flow:

```
Constructor -> Render -> Constructor -> Render -> This ERROR
```

Comment: Did you attach the refs to actual elements? Also keep in mind that the elements have to be rendered for the ref to be set. This cannot be always guaranteed so it is best to check for the refs existence.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß Yes, the refs are attached to their respective elements. How do I verify if my JSX was rendered?

Comment: Check if `this.ref.current` is not null.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß It's null

Comment: Then either the ref is not attached or the element hasn't rendered yet. So you have to set the ref at a later time.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason why you are getting the error is that **your refs are not attached to a DOM element**. If you are not trying to attach these refs to a DOM element, that means that you didn't set the initial values of your refs. Either way, the error says that your refs' values are null somehow. So, you can either:

- Pass your refs into an html element (e.g. `<div ref={myRef} />`), then React will automatically set your ref's `.current` property to the corresponding DOM node.
- Give an initial value to your refs. (As far as I know, you are not able to give an inital value to refs with `createRef`. You might need to convert your component into a functional component and then you can use `useRef` hook to give initial value to your refs.)

To have more info about refs, I suggest you to read the [React's official documentation about refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: I'm passing the refs just like you mentioned and making it a functional component is not an option.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the case in CodeSandbox?

Comment: It's work code so I can't replicate the depth of the component as it's dependent on a bunch of stuff. I wish StackOverflow had a zoom call option for help.

Comment: If you are sure that you attached your refs correctly, check the cases that refs might not be attached at mount. I strongly suggest you to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019873/10917390