# Cannot get an HTML element from the render() method using refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref, react-class-based-component

I'm trying to create a graphics editor with ReactJS. I have my `Workspace` component.This component draws objects using canvas. The `Workspace` component is a React class component.
I cannot get an HTML element, which is in the `render()` method.

I could't use `document.getElementById(..)`, I've decided to use [React Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). That's more like clean.

And I've got an error like this:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null**

```reactjs
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Workspace.css';

// Workspace component is resposiable for drawing defferent elements on the screen
// It uses canvas API to draw elements and the stuff like that
export default class Workspace extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        // Calling parent`s constructor function
        super(props);

        // All objects that will be drawn
        this.objects = [];

        // Creating the `canvasRef` ref for having access to the canvas element
        this.canvasRef = React.createRef();

        // Getting the canvas element, using the`canvasRef` ref
        const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;

        // Creating context
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="workspace">
                <canvas className="canvas" ref={this.canvasRef}></canvas>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would read your code from top to bottom, then the canvas element wouldn't exist yet before the `render` method has been called. So you you have to wait for the component to actually render once to create your context.

More specifically, wait for the `componentDidMount` method to be called and in there, create your context.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Workspace.css';

// Workspace component is resposiable for drawing defferent elements on the screen
// It uses canvas API to draw elements and the stuff like that
export default class Workspace extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        // Calling parent`s constructor function
        super(props);

        // All objects that will be drawn
        this.objects = [];

        // Creating the `canvasRef` ref for having access to the canvas element
        this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Getting the canvas element, using the`canvasRef` ref
        const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;

        // Creating context
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="workspace">
                <canvas className="canvas" ref={this.canvasRef}></canvas>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.canvasRef` will be only accessabe in componentDidMount
[componentDidMount called BEFORE ref callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074747/componentdidmount-called-before-ref-callback) the accepted answer will give You more informations. Great day!