# React ref callback updating 'this' to update child props not working

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-lifecycle, react-ref, google-map-react

I've been hitting the issue [mentioned in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074747/componentdidmount-called-before-ref-callback) where, when using the ref callback the refs are updating AFTER `componentDidMount`.

Apparently this can happen when you pass refs to elements that are being passed to a component as children, but I think I've exhausted all other options. I can't pass it to the component (`ComponentOne`) directly as it's a Styled Component and [as per the docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#refs) I get a reference to the React component instance, which AFAIK I can't access `.current` on. Nor can I wrap the component in a basic HTML element as it's being used as a marker in `'google-map-react'`, which doesn't expect one.

As a workaround I'm trying to use the ref callback to update some data using `this`, with the intention that it re-renders a child component which is being passed it via props.

Here's the code:

```
refCb = (ref, name) => {
  const { x, y } = ref.getBoundingClientRect()
  this.refsData[name] = {
    x,
    y,
  }
}

render () {
  <div>
    <ComponentOne>
      {
        this.state.list.map((listItem) => {
          return (
            <div ref={(itemRef) => {this.refCb(itemRef, listItem.name)}}></div>
          )
        }
      }
    </ComponentOne>
    <ComponentTwo
      refsData={this.refsData}
    />
  </div>
}
```

If I console log in both `refCb` and the render method of `ComponentTwo`, I can see that the `refCb` log comes in last.

I would have expected the `ComponentTwo` to re-render after, as `this.refsData` gets updated and it's being passed as props.

Am misunderstanding the component lifecycle? Any pointers would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It won't rerender, or at least it won't be stable. You need to make some kind of state, instead of

```
this.refsData[name] = {
    x,
    y,
}
```

Otherwise component won't see change and won't be able to rerender.

Comment: You can't use state in the refs callback I don't think - it forces a re-render loop. For anyone who hit's the same issue (which is very specific) I just managed to work around it by calling setState({}) in the google maps component's `onZoomAnimationEnd` prop! :)

Comment: Oh, cool! I didn't thought about re-render loop. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant solution, but for anyone who hit's the same issue (which is very specific) I just managed to work around it by calling setState({}) in the google maps component's onZoomAnimationEnd prop